Long running timers that need to survive shutdowns
What is the best way to go about creating an app that waits for a long time before running a task? Let's say I need my application to wait for 1 year and be precise to the second, what would be the best way to achieve this in ASP.NET?
I know about background services but if the I'm not sure they're intended for these cases.

I don't mean to sound nitpicky (sp?), but aren't you really talking about scheduling? Timers run for x seconds or milliseconds, etc. Schedulers or CRON jobs do things at specific times. There are other types of triggers, but Cron scheduling like in Azure would do it.

"Precise to a second" implies that you've already done the legwork on everyone's clock, including the machine at the time of setting up, the person's expectation of what time it is, the clock on the server that's executing the job, and the persistence storage to all be identical to each other. I'm not quite sure if that expectation is based on concrete experience with system times in a distributed application. You can do it if you want to, but beware that higher standards are more expensive on a cost-benefit scale.

Long running timers should be manifest as persistent data managed by processes rather than as processes themselves.

"Let's say I need my application to wait for 1 year and be precise to the second," -1, tell us about your real requirements, not something invented, then I will be happy to turn my downvote into an upvote. Good questions are based on real context, so what's yours?

... for example, any cost effective solution for this invented description will require an organizational solution prior to any technical solution, an organization which  is reponsible for the availability of the system where the task shall be run. It makes also a hell of a difference if the task has to be executed on a specific computer of your company, or if you can rent a cloud system with a contractually specificied availability (and insurance in case something goes wrong). Those are all considerations you have to make when asking for "best".

Libraries like Hangfire and Quartz exist for exactly this purpose.

@Euphoric: I don't know those libs, but I doubt they will solve the organizational issues.

@DocBrown I have kind of ignored the "precise to 1 second" requirement. I worked off the broad requirement of scheduling a task 1 year into the future. Which is what scheduling libraries like Hangfire and Quartz do for .NET. I assume OP doesn't know  about those, as he wouldn't be asking that question otherwise. Once OP has investigate this suggestion, he can come back to us if the "1 second" precision is hard requirement.

@Euphoric: the organizational problem is to make sure 1 year in the future the system where the task is scheduled for is still existing, powered on, not in maintenance mode, not compromised by a security fault, someone is paying the rental fees and energy costs, and the task it shall executed will still be needed. Once the OP has thought this through, they will hopefully come back and tell their real requirements, then I think it makes sense to start looking for a technical solution.

Wait for a year with up to 1 second precision? How would you even schedule such thing? You click one second too late and you're done? That's an artificial and completely unrealistic requirement IMO. Even waiting for concrete datetime up to 1 second seems rather unrealistic, the only real event I can think of is new years eve.

The second precision caused some chaos, what I wanted to say was to create a system that could be as precise as possible avoiding things such as periodic tasks that run once a day etc. But i think @Euphoric's suggestion of using such libraries could be an appropriate solution.

Assuming that these tasks run very infrequently, it probably isn't worth having a process run all the time. Instead I would suggest using an OS feature such as Scheduled tasks or at to start the process shortly before (typically seconds) it is required.
As the application starts up it should open database connections, prefetch any data it needs do any pre-calculations required. Once initialized, the app can check the current time and sleep for however long required until the task needs to run.
Note: Even system sleep calls can be a little imprecise, but that should be good enough for "second" precision
Once the job is complete the process can simply exit.

Per gnasher729's comment, the computer does have to be on in order to run a program and you may want to ensure it's running NTP to ensure that the clock is correct.
If it is absolutely critical that the process runs at the specific time you may need to look into HA solutions running across geographically diverse data centers.
You should also investigate solutions for distributed scheduling since you will likely run into CAP restrictions.
TL;DR - You probably can't absolutely guarantee it runs exactly once at the precise time you are looking for - you will need to make some compromises / assumptions.

I’d try to find out what you can do if the computer isn’t running at that time. And I’d try to verify that your clock information agrees with reality.

Are we there yet?
No.
Are we there yet?
No.
This is called polling. It lives at the heart of every system. One thing is very true about polling. The fewer processes doing it the better.
That's why we invented scheduling. Rather than running every random thing that decides it needs to ask if we're there yet over and over we run one thing that calls things that want to be woken up once we're there.
Every system has a solution for this. Please use it.

I thought it was a pre-teen child on a long road trip.  :)

1 year is an extreme wait, but I think the best design is to have an always running process which continually checks for or delays between runs. For example a windows service
The benefit of this over a scheduler is that you can give it a health check and alerting for when it goes down or fails to run.
Too often with schedule tasks they don't run for some reason and you don't notice. It's hard to take an alerting action when nothing is running, and to check every year that the once a year process has run is just scheduled tasks all the way down.
A windows service (or k8s console app with a loop) can

expose a http health check endpoint
which can be constantly monitored by the same altering tool you use for the rest of your stuff.
save the last run date to disk
restart if it crashes
auto start on reboot
return a bad healthcheck
if the run did not occur as expected
if the run took too long to complete
if the service hangs in some non fatal way

